# Creating Menu Slider Android

Tags: android-layout

I created a menu slider in my android app using this library http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Facebook-Style-Slide-Menu-In-Android But the site has no way to access the activitys for menu items, as I do?

Comment: Huh, can you clarify more your problem ?

Comment: ok, I followed the tutorial website, and managed to create a button that displays the menu on the left side as shown on the site, and from the menu that appears on the left has buttons, I wanted to know how to do when I click a button menu open on the left side, since this site do not teach. I want to open the left class ScreenAdmin.class by clicking on the menu button that appears on the left.

Comment: did you implemented the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the link you provided offer a pretty good tutorial, however it's not great for everyday use ( i tested it my self ), i would suggest using this library instead ;
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

The most functional 3rd library provided by jfeinstein offers a pretty easy way to implement it, and you will able to use it in no time! 
Good Luck!

Comment: I click the button to open the menu on the left. But I do not know how to create menu items for when you click on one, open the corresponding screen.